# непонятно поведение prototype

Tags: javascript

почему код срабатывает лишь в третьем случае

```js
var Army = function(units){
  var group = {units:units};
  group.prototype.attack = function(){
    console.log("army is attack");
  };
  return group;
}
var a = new Army();
a.attack();
//Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'attack' of undefined
//    at new Army (<anonymous>:3:25)
```

```js
var Army = function(units){
  var group = function(){this.units=units;};
  group.prototype.attack = function(){
    console.log("army is attack");
  };
  return group;
}
var a = new Army();
a.attack();
//Uncaught TypeError: a.attack is not a function
```

```js
var Army = function(units){
 var group = function(){this.units=units;};
 group.prototype.attack = function(){
  console.log("army is attack");
 };
 return new group();
}
var a = new Army();
a.attack();
// army is attack
```

Comment: в чем смысл возвращать что-то из конструктора? Во всех приведенных случаях `new` перед `Army` не нужен, да и сам `Army` непонятно зачем. Если его убрать, сразу станет ясно в чем проблема.

Comment: я только недавно закончил изучать шаблоны проектирования на js, недавно понял что в js нет функций - это объекты, в которых есть свойство .length и это даже не свойство а метод, вызываемый под капотом без скобочек. В книге я прочел что если в объекте нет метода, идет поиск в свойстве __proto__, также полагал что {} и new (function(){})() это одно и тоже и что им можно задавать .prototype. Из книги узнал что для производительности необходимо создавать уникальные объекты а общие методы добавлять через prototype. Вот я и столкнулся с непонятным мне поведении при применении шаблонов проектирования

Comment: ты понял неправильно. Функции в js есть. Плюс в книге ты читал про `__proto__` а тут пытался менять `prototype` - совсем другое свойство.

Comment: функция у которой есть свойство уже по определению не функция а объект

Comment: По какому определению?

Comment: по этому  var a = function(){};
console.log(a instanceof Object);
// true

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93159/discussion-between-grundy-and-mcile).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. У объекта `group` нет свойства `prototype`, поскольку свойство `prototype` - это свойство конструкторов.
2. Теперь `group` содержит конструктор, однако и возвращаете вы сам конструктор, а не объект при его помощи сконструированный. Следовательно и обращаться к методу `attack` нужно как `a.prototype.attack`, а не `a.attack`.
3. А вот в последнем случае все верно, потому что `group` - конструктор, и возвращая `new group()` вы вызываете этот конструктор, следовательно, возвращаете сконструированный им объект, который позволяет через прототип обратиться к методу `attack`.